# Coil Pack Location

Tags: engine, troubleshooting, sparkplugs

Where are the coilpacks located in a 1998 Buick LeSabre? Images would be most appreciated.

Robert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the front U.S. driver's side, unless the engine is transverse-mounted.  Google got me these:

[image: GM 3800 V6 Engine]

The above picture is of a 2004 model, but placement will probably be the same across most model years.  Another post found via Google seems to confirm this, if you presume "left side" to mean the left side of the *vehicle* and not the person working on it:

http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_do_to_change_a_Ignition_coil_on_a_98%27_buick_lesabre

> To locate ignition coil (IC): open hood, to left side of engine there are 3 IC's bolted to cylinder head; they have spark plug wires attached to them (6 wires between all 3 IC's).

[image: Coil Packs on GM 3800 V6 Engine]

Pics are from an article on UnderHoodService.com.

http://www.underhoodservice.com/Article/40247/servicing_gms_3800_v6_engines.aspx

Comment: That's a 2004 model

Comment: @Larry - Ah, I just noticed the stamp on the first pic.  You're right.  However, I imagine coil pack placement will likely be the same across most model years.  I believe a friend of mine has a LeSabre of the vintage in question.  Maybe I'll take a look under his hood if I get the chance soon.

Comment: Thanks, so to replace those, just screw them off or should I have the mechanic do it? Seems easy enough, but not for sure. Please help?!

Comment: @robertlewis2001 - I suggest posting that as a separate question.  Also, get a Chilton or Haynes manual for your vehicle.

Comment: Yeah, for replacement procedure get a service manual or alldatadiy.com