# Spark Plugs 1998 Buick Lesabre

Tags: engine, troubleshooting, sparkplugs

Where are the spark plugs in a 1998 Buick Lesabre? Pictures would be helpful as I'm a novice at this type of thing. I'm assuming I need all six because I'm getting a check engine light saying number 6 is misfiring. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your question [here](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/438/coil-pack-location) you found the coil pack, follow the spark plug wires to the other end where you will find the plugs. They are in the side of the head where the exhaust manifold comes out. You should be able to see three of them fairly easily from the front of the car.

The back are a little more difficult to get to at. You will need to take both of the "dog bone" engine mounts loose so you can rock the engine toward the front of the car to give you enough room to get to the back side of the engine. You can use tie down strap to pull the engine toward the front and hold it there to give you access.

Spark plugs are circled below.

[image: Spark plug location picture]

The dog bone mount is shown below

[image: Dog bone engine mount picture]

Comment: Even though the engines are

Answer (score 2):

A costly mistake (that I just made) while rotating engine forward to gain access to the rear sparkplugs:

You can end up with your keys locked in the car.

Many sites recommend that you put the car into neutral prior to loosening the "dogbone" which lets you rotate the engine forward more easily.  In order to put the car into neutral the obvious thing is to put the key in the ignition, shift to neutral, get out and go to work.  However, if you close the door, the car will automatically lock the doors because it is in neutral.